# How to fix an error: Cannot access a disposed object,Object name: 'Images'

Tags: c#, winforms

hello guys i have an error, but i don't know why it just pops up occasionally, well sometimes there's no error sometimes it okay and now it's okay and i can't find where the hell this error because it okay, and sometimes it was there.

```
if (globalVariables.sBarcodeValidation.IndexOf("Images") + 1 > 0)
        {
            globalVariables.aErrorDisp = globalVariables.sBarcodeValidation.Split('|');
            globalVariables.gCN = globalVariables.aErrorDisp[1];
            if (globalVariables.bOCR == true)
            {
                //Images.DefaultInstance.Show(); //technically this is the first code here but
                Images image = new Images();//i replace it with this
                image.Show();// and this
            }
            txtBarCode.Text = string.Empty;
            return;
        }
```

here in the first page i'm calling a form form called 'Images' if the `globalVariables.sBarcodeValidation` contains a word Images then this code will execute inside the form of Images.

```
private void Images_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
        string sImageValidation = null;
        string[] aImages = null;                     
        int ctr = 0;
        btnChange.Text = "Change Record to " + globalVariables.gCN;
        sImageValidation = string.Empty;
        int x = int.Parse(new ImagesRepository().GetContainers(Settings.Default.BoothID));
        int j = 0;
        ctr = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= x; j++)
        {
            sImageValidation = new ImagesRepository().GetWKCounter(Settings.Default.BoothID, j);
            aImages = sImageValidation.Split(';');
            ctr = dgTruckQueue.Rows.Count - 1;
            dgTruckQueue.Rows.Insert(ctr, aImages[0], aImages[1], aImages[2], aImages[3], aImages[4]);
        }
        dgTruckQueue.Sort(dgTruckQueue.Columns[4], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
```

and after this code loaded

i'll click the button called 'btnProceed'

```
private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sImageValidation = null;
        if (globalVariables.ulevel == "In-Gate")
        {
            sImageValidation = new ImagesRepository().LogMegaports(globalVariables.gCN, "401");
        }
        else if (globalVariables.ulevel == "Out-Gate")
        {
            sImageValidation = new ImagesRepository().LogMegaports(globalVariables.gCN, "302");
        }
        globalVariables.bOCR = false;
        Close();
    }
```

i already tested this a numerous times and sometimes, it's throwing an error  `Cannot access a disposed object,Object name: 'Images'` i really don't know how to find this guy i'll appreciate any comments thank you.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: What is Images class? COuld you please share it also?

Comment: if the globalVariables.sBarcodeValidation contains a word Image then this code will execute inside the form of Images. sometimes this is where the error and sometimes i dont getting any error any i don't know why the hell it's not throwing an error now.

Comment: Images is not a class  globalVariables.sBarcodeValidation this is where the word Images will come from to database.